# Baggage left at airport , not lost can hubby pick it ip

Tags: luggage

I left a bag at baggage claim in La Guardia.

United found it and it’s in baggage claim.

I can’t get back there to pick it up but my hubby is landing there today.

Will they release my luggage to him if I send him a pic of my bag receipt and picture ID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call the airline, get yourself connected to the baggage office at LaGuardia, and explain the situation: they will be able to help.

Edit after comment from Zach Lipton:
Perhaps try the airport operator at (718) 533-3400 and ask if they can connect you to the United baggage office.

Comment: Exactly, there is always some kind of "lost&found" office in airports that can get you back inside the baggage claim area so you can pick up your bags. You don't need to get a new flight in order to pick up forgotten bags, that would've been ridiculous...

Comment: In the US, the baggage claim for domestic flights is generally openly accessible anyway. The question seems to indicate the poster's husband has a flight arriving at that airport anyway, not booked specifically to retrieve the lost bag.

Comment: Right, he just happens to be flying in at the airport and I’m hoping he can grab it. I’m still waiting to hear bad from United in regards to my situation. When you try to call them the call is answers in India , not New York

Comment: @Bucu I would try to get hold of the actual United baggage handling office at LaGuardia, not the normal customer service call center, since they're the ones that have your bag. Perhaps try the airport operator at (718) 533-3400 and ask if they can connect you to the United baggage office.

Answer (score 2):

If it was still in the carousel area then he could pick it up as the baggage claim area is generally not secured in the USA and rarely are tags matched against bags.

However, if it was pulled off by the baggage claim office and stored in their secure area, they will often ask for the baggage tag or for your ID so that they can match the bag with you. In this case, it’s best to phone ahead and let them know hubby is picking it up for you.

Comment: I did call and they weren’t sure they would release it , I can’t call them directly only the India customer service line. But they also won’t send it because they didn’t lose it , i accidentally left it behind so I’m not sure what other options I’m gonna have.

Comment: I’m hoping with a pic of my Id on his phone and a pic of my baggage receipt that they will do it

Comment: @Bucu that should do it. Especially if he can phone you and have you verify that he is authorized. Just tell him to be polite and friendly. Baggage claim are used to people being angry at them so they appreciate people who are friendly.